# Display LinkedIn shares from other organizations

Tags: linkedin-api

I am working on prototype to display our partner's LinkedIn feed/shares on our website.

I cannot find API to query partner's LinkedIn feeds. The Share API (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/share-api) seems to be limited to our own feeds/shares only.

We cannot use any of client side code or iframes or LinkedIn plugins. All data should be collected on server side.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

> our application may retrieve the collection of shares owned by a
>   specific member or organization. Just use URNs of format
>   urn:li:person:{id}, urn:li:organization:{id}, or
>   urn:li:organizationBrand:{id} to retrieve shares for the relevant
>   entity.

this is literatlly at the top of the page

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners={URN}&sharesPerOwner=100
```

so in this instance URN is :

- urn:li:person:{id}
- urn:li:organization:{id}
- urn:li:organizationBrand:{id}

Comment: Thanks for you reply. This API will give you shares from your organization, but I am interested in shares from other companies.
Also, there is a note in documentation which prohibits getting data if you are not admin in organization:
_For personal shares, you may only retrieve shares for the authorized members.
For organization shares, you may only retrieve shares for organizations for which the authorized member is an administrator. See Organization Access Control for details._

Comment: oh so you are no member of the organization ?

then the api wont work for you. the only option left for you is datascraping.
the company/organization pages require you to be an administrator of the page.